# INSERT SELECT JAVA JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, select, jdbc, insert

How do I insert  all records from another table using insert select?

```
       try {
        PreparedStatement st=dc.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO timerecord (empno)  SELECT empno FROM Employeemaster WHERE empstatus = 'Active'" );

        i=st.executeUpdate();
        if (i>0) {
            dc.getConnection().commit();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Database Error: "+e.getMessage());
       return;
    }
```

Comment: what error are you getting?  Also, you might want to use a swing worker to decouple a potentially long running operation from the event dispatch thread.

Comment: Is the above query not working? What error are you getting

Comment: provide the stack trace too if possible...

Comment: The error that I get is Database error; You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MYSQL version

Comment: @cassrynne That makes it more of a MySQL question.

Comment: does that statement work in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the syntax error is not related to Java or your formatting by running the statement directly with the database before trying to go further.

Also, one of the advantages of a PreparedStatement is that you can include parameters instead of hard coding things like 'Active'.   This will help prevent other syntax errors.